# Create view without SUPER privileges in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to via SQL tab within the phpmyadmin to create/import a view like this:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`byname`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `wr_averages` AS select `nf_users`.`id` AS `id`,(`nf_users`.`points` / `nf_users`.`played`) AS `average_points` from `nf_users` where (`nf_users`.`played` > 24);
```

I get this error:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

I can not get SUPER privileges at my hosting company, so is there anyway to get around this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: No, you can't get around that.

Comment: Another way which i believe can be done is to create a testing view in the database that you are using. Export the testing view and see the username and use it.

Comment: Check the definer, should not be `username@localhost` unless explicitly needed, but `username@%`

Answer (score 19):

From the documentation:

*If you specify the DEFINER clause, you cannot set the value to any user but your own unless you have the SUPER privilege. These rules determine the legal DEFINER user values:*

- *If you do not have the SUPER privilege, the only legal user value is your own account, either specified literally or by using CURRENT_USER. You cannot set the definer to some other account.*
- *If you have the SUPER privilege, you can specify any syntactically legal account name. If the account does not actually exist, a warning is generated.*

Check your MySQL account, it is not `byname`@`localhost`.

Solutions:

- Create new view with DEFINER clause using account that granted with SUPER privilege.
- Do not use DEFINER clause in CREATE VIEW, in this case MySQL will create view DEFINER = CURRENT_USER.

Comment: In simpler terms, definer should not be `username@localhost` unless explicitly needed, but `username@%`

Comment: replacing every occurance of DEFINER=`xname`@`%` with DEFINER = CURRENT_USER in a simple text editor worked for me.